# projection operator is isometric

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $P:X\rightarrow Y$ be projection operator between to vactor spaces $X$ and $Y$

P is  always isometric or not

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Show your work.

Comment: How is an isometry between vector spaces defined? Dont we need some extra structure to talk about that?

Comment: what about $P=0$?

Comment: What is your definition of a projection operator when it is a map between different vector spaces with no relation between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X= \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\mathbb{R}$. Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be the projection $p(x,y)=x$. We have $|p(x,y)-p(x',y')|=|x-x'|$ so not necessarily.